# Why does my Eclipse plugin show up in Eclipse RCP version, but not in other versions like Java and Java EE?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have developed an Eclipse plugin using the RCP version of Eclipse. I have used the plugin via a 'run application' launch as well as by exporting the plugin as a JAR and putting it in the plugins directory of Eclipse RCP.

The problem is that when I put the plugin JAR in the plugins directory for my Java version or Java EE version of Eclipse, it doesn't seem to be loaded as one of the plugins. I go to the preferences to look at the pref. page for my plugin and it isn't even listed.

This is my first Eclipse plugin, so I don't have much experience using plugins across different distributions of Eclipse and so forth. Any ideas of how to fix this? I would like to be able to use the plugin in any Eclipse (Java, Java EE, RCP, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your plugin under install/dropins/plugins directory. As of Eclipse 3.5, adding plugins directly to the root plugins directory isn't supported.

This should be enough for you to experiment further, but this isn't a good way to install finished plugins. The best way to install plugins is via a published repository. You will need to create a feature to hold your plugin and then use Export -> Plug-in Development -> Deployable features wizard or investigate command line build solutions such as pdeBuild.

Comment: In my eclipse directory, I tried putting the plugin JAR in dropins/plugins and this didn't seem to work. So I then just put it straight inside of dropins which also didn't work (Note. There was nothing in dropins, I had to create the plugins directory manually).

Comment: Is there some way to view some sort of error log for plugins? I am guessing that my plugin just isn't successfully launching, but I have no way of determining the source of problems because I don't have any sort of error log.

Comment: You may need to create a feature for deployment to work even in the dropins directory case. I do not know if there is a log you can look in.

Comment: Part of my problem was that I was missing one of my plugin's dependencies, but it also helps to put the JARs in the dropins folder. Thanks!